# Error when adding stopPropagation to contextMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have downloaded the current version of JQuery-contextMenu plugin, and created a test page. In the test page if I use li elements the function propagates from the top li item down to the lower li items. Is there a method to stop this from happening? Thank you for your help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="src/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="src/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $.contextMenu({
                    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
                    callback: function(key, options) {
                        var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        alert(m); 
                    },
                    items: {
                        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                        "sep1": "---------",
                        "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                            return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                        }}
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span><br>

        <span class=" btn btn-neutral">right click me</span><br>
        <ul >
            <li class="Docs context-menu-one" style="list-style-type: none;"> Testing
                <ul >
                    <li class="upTest" style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <a href="#">dfasfsdafas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class=" btn btn-neutral">right click me</span><br>
        <span class=" btn btn-neutral">right click me</span><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to check the documentation on contextMenu. Because that is not what stopPropagation does and that is not how you use it.

Comment: I have looked, but I was unable to find anything that would achieve the same result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the right click function from being passed down to objects with the class upTest.

Comment: You can try to prevent the click event with `.click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();})` However that is not going to solve your problem. You need to check what the equivalent is in that library you are using. If there isn't one then I suggest you find another one that suits your needs. If you can set up a basic jsfiddle I can play with I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing I found by adding an additional contextmenu and assigning none to the trigger, I received the results I wanted.

$(function(){
$.contextMenu({
selector: '.upTest', 
trigger: 'none', 
});
});